# Adding an event into a dictionary

Tags: c#, .net, events, dictionary

I have the following event code:

```
public delegate void SomeEventHandler(SomeEventArgs eventArgs);
event SomeEventHandler someEvent;
```

My scenario involves event usage such that for each SomeType1, there's an arbitrary number of SomeType2, with an event associated with it.

Example,

```
public event SomeEventHandler EventA1EventB1
public event SomeEventHandler EventA1EventB2
public event SomeEventHandler EventA1EventB3
...
public event SomeEventHandler EventA1EventBn
```

Followed by,

```
public event SomeEventHandler EventA2EventB1
...
```

Given the arbitrary number of the above combinations (and the rather messy code), I opted for:

```
Dictionary<SomeType1, Dictionary<SomeType2, SomeEventHandler>>
```

Problem, of course, is that you can't add the above event declaration to a dictionary. For this, I just used,

```
delegate { }
```

I build up the above dictionary as follows:

```
var someType2Dictionary = Dictionary<SomeType2, delegate { }>();

someType1Dictionary.Add(someType1, someType2Dictionary);
```

Later on, I look up like so,

```
someType1Dictionary[someLookUpKey1][someLookUpKey2] += someEventOfTypeSomeEventHandler
```

First of all, is there a better way of dealing with the above scenario?

And second, when running, the same event/delegate (for any look-up) always fires or I get a null for the returned value in the second dictionary.

Comment: Why do you declare the inner dictionary `var someType2Dictionary = Dictionary<SomeType2, delegate { }>();`, should'nt it be `var someType2Dictionary = Dictionary<SomeType2, SomeEventHandler>();`? Also your question is a little hard to follow, can you put in your real types to help make it easier to understand what you are trying to do instead of `SomeType1`. Also since `SomeType1` and `SomeType2` are being used as dictionary keys do they have `.GetHashCode()` and `Equals()` overrided correctly?

Comment: With such an number of event, please explain why you don't have A1 and B1 as argument of a single event, or any other way to use parameters rather than a crowd of static definition.

Comment: I solved the problem. The issue was not relevant to any of the above code. ScottChamberlain, you're correct; it was a typo (I typed out the sample by hand). Next time, I'll stick with copying/pasting code in here. @GameAlchemist Unfortunately, I'm working with an existing API DLL that I have no control over, so I have to work with what I have.